# Problems while Inserting data or create table or updating data using Oracle and PHP

Tags: php, oracle10g

I'm new in PHP. I'm trying to insert data into the table. while running the program it's showing successful but when checking in oracle 10g database it's showing ***no data found***. Same thing happened when creating table,it's showing  ***table or view doesn't exist.***

Here is my code=

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1><u>Inserting data into Table</u></h1>

<?php
// Create connection
$conn = oci_connect('SYSTEM', 'xxxx', 'localhost/XE');
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . oci_error());
}


$sql = "insert into MYGUESTS (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL) values (12, 'John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
$stid=oci_parse($conn, $sql);
if(!$stid){
$e=oci_error($conn);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}
else
 {
    echo "Successfull";
 }
oci_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

why i can't see any data in oracle database? where is the problem?

Comment: Are you committing the data after the insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `commit` and `execute`

An OCI example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-commit.php):

```
<?php

// Insert into several tables, rolling back the changes if an error occurs

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO mysalary (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Chris')");

// The OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT flag tells Oracle not to commit the INSERT immediately
// Use OCI_DEFAULT as the flag for PHP <= 5.3.1.  The two flags are equivalent
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
if (!$r) {    
    $e = oci_error($stid);
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO myschedule (startday) VALUES (12)');
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
if (!$r) {    
    $e = oci_error($stid);
    oci_rollback($conn);  // rollback changes to both tables
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Commit the changes to both tables
$r = oci_commit($conn);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($conn);
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

?>
```